# Can't turn on bluetooth

Tags: dual-boot, bluetooth

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my lenovo laptop with windows 10

I can't turn on bluetooth in Ubuntu but in windows 10 bluetooth working perfectly

In terminal #bluetoothctl shows no default controller available

How to fix this

```
prasanna@prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
prasanna@prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b581 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
prasanna@prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] password for prasanna: 
[   10.577635] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.577704] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   10.577707] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.577760] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.577766] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.577777] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.154958] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[   24.183977] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   24.183987] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   24.183997] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

prasanna@prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ sudo apt install bluetooth
[sudo] password for prasanna: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
bluetooth is already the newest version (5.64-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 146 not upgraded.

prasanna@prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service is masked.)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-06-13 20:44:49 IST; 33min ago
   Main PID: 9557 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
        CPU: 88ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─9557 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 13 20:44:49 prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 13 20:44:49 prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25 bluetoothd[9557]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jun 13 20:44:49 prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 13 20:44:49 prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25 bluetoothd[9557]: Starting SDP server
Jun 13 20:44:49 prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25 bluetoothd[9557]: Bluetooth management i>
Jun 13 20:46:16 prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Current c>

prasanna@prasanna-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: All looks good to me. Did you update the system? It looks like there is some bug in a recent update. There are many similar questions about quite different devices. According to your output all should work.

Comment: I just installed the os yesterday and I didn't update anything

Comment: did you turn off fast boot in Windows? try turning on Bluetooth in windows, turning off fast boot, and then booting Ubuntu.

Comment: I turned off fast boot in windows but no difference nothing changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279646/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available Here there are quite different solutions, perhaps it helps, like trying with ```sudo bluetoothctl```